# Undefined index in php script after a POST form

Tags: php

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$ppassword = $_POST['password'];
$password = md5("$ppassword");
```

This is the code and i am getting this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\php\compare.php on line 14
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  250440  {main}( )   ..\lognet.php:0
2   0.0007  260000  include( 'C:\wamp\www\php\compare.php' )    ..\lognet.php:3


Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp\www\php\compare.php on line 15
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  250440  {main}( )   ..\lognet.php:0
2   0.0007  260000  include( 'C:\wamp\www\php\compare.php' )    ..\lognet.php:3
```

here is the form:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="compare.php">
<strong><input id="close" type="button" value="X"                                     
onclick="getElementById('loginbox').style.display = 'none'">Member Login</strong></br>
Username:<input name="username" type="text" id="username"></br>
Password:<input name="password" type="password" id="password">
&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;</br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

I had it working but when they up dated the php to 5.4.12 It stoped and i had to change it.

Comment: can you show us your form's code ? Also add print_r($_POST); before your php code to see what are values you got from your form

Comment: can you show the form that you use to send data to the php page ?

Comment: @Deepu: how html will be helpful for php question?

Comment: This is really basic, you should've searched over Google instead of asking a question here

Comment: Why you guys down-vote so quickly, he seems new to the community.

Comment: @zerkms yes it will be, if OP is not using `name="username"` in his HTML form

Comment: @Mr. Alien: will using a proper name save you from undefined index error in case if someone requests that page directly or by requesting it with `curl`?

Comment: @zerkms Well, I don't think OP is going that far

Comment: @Mr. Alien: well, how about explaining that it's a PHP issue and has nothing to do with html? I know learning newbies is boring, but giving them false expectations is even worse.

Comment: @ra_htial: and probably seems new to the internet?

Comment: @zerkms yes you are right, but I am just going to the base here, least I can tell him without the markup is that he missed out the name attributes or they are not spelled correctly

Comment: @Mr. Alien: then be ready that tomorrow he will ask the same question about fetching data from database. Another day - reading data from file. Newbies treat programming as a set of magic casts, each of which is unique and specific for some area.

Comment: @zerkms aah yes, I got your point.. :)

Comment: I am no newbie. I can code in several different languages including: javascript, HTML5, CSS3, C+, and others. I have certifications such as the CompTIA Strata. and I placed in the web design competition in BPA(Business Professionals of America)

Comment: I fix it. never mine.

Answer (score 0):

use isset() function to check either variable set or not?

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';

$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? md5($_POST['password']) : '';
```

// Your html code goes here and make sure your html **text field name** should match with **$_POST['variable_name']**

Comment: Thats not a good solution.The html he is using is the problem.

Comment: yes, I didn't downvoted your answer, but what if OP has username filled and he left password field blank? He will again get undefined index password

Comment: I downvoted the question, because it won't solve the problem (even if you check for password: the problem is in the form not in the php script). It's like treating a gunshot wound with a child's band aid

Comment: @Mr.Alien but error is clearly saying that $_POST[] variable is not set... so we have given this answer

Comment: @Mr. Alien: "blank" item would be an empty string

Comment: I have that else where in the code because it also prevents  other things from doing things.\

Comment: @zerkms ahh yes ofcourse I forgot, -Coder What I meant was what if username is set but not the password, still he will encounter same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? md5($_POST['password']) : '';
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have for example this code in the same page of your html form you need this:

```
if(isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['username'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$ppassword = $_POST['password'];
$password = md5("$ppassword");

}
```

if you have this code in other page confirm if you are receiving the post values with

```
echo $_POST['username'];
echo $_POST['password'];
```

If not you are setting up wrong your inputs

```
<form action="somepage.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="username" value="" />

<input type="password" name="password" value="" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but you haven't completely solved the problem - what if `$_POST['username']` is set, but `$_POST['password']` isn't?

Comment: If he confirms all the steps that I have in my answer I think that he solves the problem but ok EDITED, thanks for the tip if(isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['username'])){